# showing that Data1.map is not function

Tags: reactjs, function

i want to use data by using map but its showing default.map is not a function

```
import React from 'react';
import Ques from './Ques'
import Data1 from './QData'
function Demo()
{
       const QuesData= Data1.map(joke=> <Ques question={joke.Question} answer={joke.Answer} />)

        return(<div>{QuesData}</div>)    
}
export default Demo
```

> TypeError: _QData__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.map is not a
>   function

Comment: can you format your code a bit and show us, how Ques looks like?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you export Data1 from './QData' as default. see below example for Qdata file

```
export default data = [{joke1Data}, {joke2Data}, ...];
```

Comment: Great it works!
Feel free to accept it as solution :). And if you can give some rate, I'll appreciate.
Thanks